# No cursor (or invisible) in active text field after UIAlertView dismissed via cancel button

Tags: ios

I have a project that began life with an IOS target of 5.0 while I was using Xcode4x.  Today I am using XCode5.

In IOS7 only, after I show a UIAlertView with only one button (the default cancel button which I have titled "OK"), the app will no longer show a flashing cursor in any text field on the same view.  The keyboard will come up and I can edit the text field, but no cursor is shown anymore.  If I jump to another text field on a different view, i get the cursor.  Going back to the original view, touch a text field, no cursor.

Here is the code I am using for the alert view:

```
            UIAlertView *alertView; // New alertview Test
            alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test Alert" message: @"Test Mesage" delegate: Nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: Nil];
           [alertView show]; //
```

I have created a new project in XCode5 targetting back to IOS6 and the problem is not present.  It is something in my project.

I hope someone has some ideas.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the exact problem and it is a bug.  In Xcode 5.0.1, in my current project or in a brand new project, the GLOBAL TINT COLOR property of the storyboard is not being applied to the UITextField's at launch.  It is however being applied on a re-draw, for example in my case when the UIAlertView is dismissed.  To prove this, I changed my GLOBAL TINT COLOR to gray.  Prior to the UIAlertview the UITextFiled cursor is blue (default). After the UIAlertview the UITextField has changed to gray.  I have updated my bug report with Apple.

Just to clarify, initially I was thinking that the cursor was no longer appearing.  In fact it was changing colors to white, which is what I had the GLOBAL TINT COLOR set to.  Other controls on the interface were being tinted with white in real time in Xcode and at launch.  However the UITextFields were not getting tinted until after the app is running and AFTER the UIAlertview was shown and then dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in UIKit. Have you tried calling becomeFirstResponder on text field after alert view is dismissed?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have multiple text fields so I just added your suggestion to the 'Editing Did Begin' send event of all text fields like this:  '[sender becomeFirstResponder];'  That has made no change.

Comment: Are you sure that this event is sent after dismissing the alert view?

Comment: Another thing could be to send 2 consecutive messages after dismissing that alert: first resignFirstResponder and after that becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: The becomeFirstResponder is sent from touching the text field, so yes it is definitely after the alert view is dismissed.  What would I send resignFirstResponder to?

Comment: I have submitted this as a bug.  Bug# 15357486

Comment: This definitely has to be a bug.  I have found workaround!  If I set the tint color of all the text fields AFTER the alert view is dismissed using: **textField.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];** the cursors return and they are red!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after playing around with some settings found that it comes down to having tint set to a color and not default.

It has to be a bug because it doesn't matter what color you set tint to the flashing cursor is dark blue.

Tint is found by going to inspector then scroll down to View. Tint is below Background and Alpha.

Be sure to share this as I haven't seen an answer for this problem anywhere.